# Failure to add new directory path to run python script in terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, directory, path

I know this has been discussed a bunch but nothing I have read online has worked. Note: I am a novice at terminal. Running Mac OS 10.14.5 Mojave

I am able to run Python scripts in terminal if I first enter:

```
cd PythonScripts
```

(which is the folder they live in: `/Users/myname/PythonScripts`)

My goal is to be able to run `./myscript.py` from terminal without having to tell it where to look each time, so I want to permanently add the PythonScripts folder to the directory path.

I have tried `sudo nano /etc/paths` and added `/Users/myname/PythonScripts`
I save and restart terminal and check it with `echo $PATH` and see it's been added. I then try `./myscript.py` and get the message:

> -bash: ./myscript.py: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong? Again, I don't know the lingo, just following what I read online.

Comment: Specifying `./` means "in the current directory"; to look up your script via `PATH`, just use `myscript.py`. Also, I'd recommend adding a file in /etc/paths.d instead of editing /etc/paths -- that's likely to get overwritten by things like system updates. Except... putting your personal binaries directory (/Users/yourname/anything) in a system-wide config file (/etc/anything) is generally a bad idea; I'd either install the script system-wide (probably in /usr/local/bin) or just adding the directory to `PATH` in your account's shell init file(s).

Answer (score 0):

1) You need in your python script a header like this (set this to your python location)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

2) Add your folder to your Path on your .zshrc or .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/Users/myname/PythonScripts:$PATH
```

3) Set execution permissions for every script you want to run

```
chmod + x myscript.py
```

Open a new terminal and you should be able to call myscript.py from anywhere